# BugSense unable to log catched exception

Tags: ios, bugsense

I have integrated BugSense library available at [HERE](https://www.bugsense.com/releases/ios/3.5.1/download) in my iOS project.

When my application crashed because of `uncauchgt exception` I can see details in "Errors" bookmark. But when I try to log catched exception (via BUGSENSE_LOG macro), no error details are visible. I want to check my trial version before upgrade.

Could anyone explain me what's wrong? I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** My problem was because I've tried to log exception which wasn't directly throwed. Somewhere in my code I throw exception (let's suppose A) and in try-catch statement this exception was handled. In catch statement I've created another exception (let's suppose B) by call initWithName: reason: userInfo: and set exception A as caused to B. Log exception B failed, but when I logged A, it works!